# Were Bubble Bobble cheats always available in the arcade?

Tags: cheats, arcade, bubble-bobble

The original Bubble Bobble provides well-know cheat codes (e.g. "Power-up", "Original" mode, etc.).

In one guide, I've read that in order for them to work, the arcade need a dip switch to be enabled (or something like that).

Now, I think I couldn't find such dip switch in the emulated ROM I play with (on MAME), so I have a doubt: is such switch real, or it doesn't exist (and consequently, cheats were available on all the arcade Bubble Bobble machines)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](https://archive.org/details/arcademanual_bub-bob) doesn't mention it so I think that one guide is probably wrong, AFAIK the Power Up! cheat worked on all arcade machines.